# Bot framework composer dynamic multiple choice

Tags: bot-framework-composer

Hi I am bulding a (test) shopping assistant bot with **bot framework composer** (V2)
I have a list called user.lists.cart where I add items
these items are object with following structure

```
{

"Id": "10",

"Item": "Flour",

"Brand": "Brailla",

"Type": "Wheat",

"Image": "https://www.laspesa24.com/26655-thickbox_default/barilla-farina-tipo-00-1000g.jpg",

"Price": 0.72
}
```

I would like to implement a remove item from cart operation,
so I need a multiple choice enabling the user to select the item he would like to remove
how can I achieve that?
thanks

Comment: did you managed to solve this?

Comment: no, i used a workaround where you have to write the whole item name... (no buttons)
maybe a custom c# action maybe needed to generate the json for this case